# Flutter Dart Setter Problem When Using Set keyword

Tags: flutter, dart, setter, bloc

Being introduced to BLoC, I create a simple class that alters the value of a `bool` variable:

```
class SignInBloc {
  
  StreamController<bool> _isLoading = StreamController<bool>();

  Stream<bool> get getIsLoading => _isLoading.stream;
  set setIsLoading(bool isLoading) => _isLoading.sink.add(isLoading); // Here is my problem (set)

  void dispose(){
    _isLoading.close();
  }
}
```

When I use the `set` keyword and then call for it in my UI screen: `bloc.setIsLoading(false);`
I get an exception:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setIsLoading'.
```

But when I take off the `set` keyword in my `SignInBloc` class, it works fine. I am confused, isn't it best to use this keyword rather than directly declaring my setter? and,
Why do I not get an error when I take it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setters are meant to be used as if they were public fields of the class. You're just explicitly defining your own setter. Directly assign your intended value to the setter like so:

```dart
bloc.setIsLoading = false;
```

The only benefit of using `set` is being able to use this syntax.

When you take off `set`, it's being changed to a normal method where `bloc.setIsLoading(false);` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, if I don't use the ```set``` keyword I will have to write ```bloc.setIsLoading(flase);``` in order for me to alter the value?

Comment: Thank you very much, will check this as an answer in 10 mins.